# HttpWebRequest not downloading all data

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm trying to download xml files using httpwebrequest using the code below based on [this example here.](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Data-Access-Strategies-HttpWebRequest.aspx) Now it works partially in that it doesn't download all the xml file's contents. Any idea why?

```
 public void download(String url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.BeginGetResponse(a =>
        {
            StringBuilder data=null;
            using (WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(a))
            {
                int expected = (int)response.ContentLength;

                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        int read = 0;
                        data = new StringBuilder(expected);
                        char[] buffer = new char[1024];

                        while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            data.Append(new string(buffer, 0, read));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("exception caught: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got \n " + data.ToString());
        }, null);
    }
```

Comment: whats the buffer size u have set???

Comment: try increasing the buffer size.

Comment: @Apoorva I increased the buffer from 1k to 8k to 16k still no difference in the data read.

Comment: What type of data are u receiving?

Comment: i'm receiving just xml http://java.sun.com/developer/earlyAccess/xml/examples/samples/two_gent.xml to be precise

Comment: How did you find that "it doesn't download all the xml file's contents"? I've checked data.ToString().Length = expected = 164619

Comment: because when i display the contents it's not complete that's how.

Comment: This looks to be downloading the entire xml content for the url you have posted. Have you stepped through this in your debugger and verified the content of `data`? How are you displaying the string? This may be where your problem is. If you're writing it out somewhere, make sure you are flushing your stream.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're getting is XML, you can use [XDocument.Load(stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to load the result to a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instance

Your problem may be with the applied Encoding, and this method should solve any Encoding issue!